# How to upgrade php from old version to new version

Tags: upgrade, php, fedora-14

How to upgrade php from old version to new version.
Say from php 5.3.3 to php 5.3.5?

Answer (score 0):

if possible, get the latest version of LAMP. it contains PHP and MySQL and Apache